# Delete Kaizala Group without losing Jobs in Kaizala Admin Management Portal

Tags: kaizala

Is it possible to dissolve Kaizala group without losing jobs from management portal. Because we need job done or undone history for our reports. I try to delete a test group from admin portal so i delete every message and jobs which created in group meeting.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to dissolve Kaizala groups without losing the group content/data, including Jobs, survey and other Actions